# How do I allow MATLAB to read a text file containing a list of angles in degrees, arcmins and arcseconds?

Tags: matlab

I have a text file containing a bunch of right ascension and declination values (quoted in arc min and sec) for a bunch of sky objects along side their corresponding brightness.

They adopt the following format: 12:55:35.52

I understand how to extract them into a cell array and I have converted them to a large array. However if I attempt to any mathematical operations with them, it results in a 1x0 matrix.

I am assuming this is due to MATLAB not recognising the format and being unable to read their values. Is this the correct assumption? If so how can I get around this?

Full File format:

```
 12:55:35.74   0:00:55.4  INDEF  INDEF
 12:55:35.52  -0:02:32.9  11.829  0.004
 12:55:35.29  -0:01:15.2  15.756  0.111
 12:55:35.15   0:00:42.4  13.421  0.015
 12:55:35.14   0:00:34.0  INDEF  INDEF
 12:55:35.03   0:03:01.2  15.364  0.077
 12:55:34.95   0:03:58.8  21.016  14.655
 12:55:34.79  -0:02:20.5  INDEF  INDEF
 12:55:34.68  -0:02:30.1  15.535  0.087
 12:55:34.22  -0:02:39.1  18.067  0.940
 12:55:33.81  -0:01:15.0  19.359  3.107
```

Comment: Show us a [mcve]. We can not help if you dont show us the code. Please take the [tour] and learn  [ask]

Comment: Please provide the code, too, as its what its failing, I assume

Answer (score 0):

You might want to convert them to radians for easy summation.

- 1 degree = 2*pi/360 radians
- 1 arcminute = 2*pi/(360*60) radians
- 1 arcsecond = 2*pi/(360*3600) radians

In your example:

`12*2*pi/360 + 55*pi/(360*60) + 35.52*2*pi/(360*3600) = 0.2176`

For a file named `test.txt`, containing your example data it woud look something like this:

```
fid = fopen('test.txt','rt');
d=textscan(fid,' %.0f:%.0f:%.2f    %.0f:%.0f:%.1f  %.3f  %.3f','TreatAsEmpty','INDEF');
fclose(fid);
d = cell2mat(d);
res = d(:,1:3) .* [2*pi/360 , pi/(360*60) , 2*pi/(360*3600)];
sum(res,2)

>>
   0.217612208387255
   0.217611141797157
   0.217610026725690
   0.217609347986537
   0.217609299505169
   0.217608766210120
   0.217608378359175
   0.217607602657285
   0.217607069362236
   0.217604839219303
   0.217602851483210
```

Comment: Let's find out. Probably something goes wrong somewhere in the import process. Reads it as a string maybe? This minimal example uses textscan to read it as numeric values and does a conversion to radians. If this does not work on his pc we can exclude a lot of simple mistakes.